Popularity Trends Usage Report showing zero for only two pages
The usage report is showing zeros for only two pages, despite actual hits on these sites. These pages are the home pages of two sub-sites. All other pages have correct report results; only these two show zeros.
We have connected to search service farm and Search Service application is connected to the web application. Search is actively crawling the content. Both the Usage Data Import and Usage Data Processing timer jobs are running on time. I checked the event receivers and they are enabled.
Since all other pages have correct reports, I don't think the problem is with the settings or services. I'm not sure what else to check to fix the issue.
Does anyone have any suggestions?
